# json-serverにポストすると ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED エラーが発生する

Tags: next.js

docker-compose環境でnext.js13のフロントエンドからモック用のjson-serverにfetch関数でpostしたところ、下図のようなエラーが発生しました。/articles/newの「投稿」ボタンクリックでjson-serverへpostしています。色々と調査したものの解決に至らず、手助けいただけると助かります。

[image: エラー画面]

#### 調査

コンソールでERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVEDとエラーが出ているため、名前解決関連の問題かと考えていますが、createArticle単体でテストしたところ、問題なくpostできています。テストは/check/page.tsxを作成して動作確認をしました。

#### ソースコード

- ./compose.yml

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./.docker
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
    command: sh -c "npm run dev"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - next-app-network
    depends_on:
      json-server:
        condition: service_started

  json-server:
    build:
      context: ./json-server/.docker
    ports:
     - '3001:3001'
    volumes:
      - ./json-server/data:/data
    networks:
      - next-app-network
    command: json-server --watch db.json --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3001
networks:
  next-app-network:
```

- ./app/src/blogAPI.ts

```
export const createArticle = async (
    id: string,
    title: string,
    content: string
): Promise<Article> => {
    const currentDatetime = new Date().toISOString()

    const res = await fetch('http://json-server:3001/posts', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ id, title, content, createdAt: currentDatetime })
    })

    if (!res.ok){
        throw new Error("エラーが発生しました。")
    }

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))

    const newArticle = await res.json()
    return newArticle
}
```

- ./app/src/app/articles/new/page.tsx

```
"use client"

import React from 'react'
import { createArticle  } from '@/blogAPI'
import { useState } from 'react'

const CreateBlogPage = () => {
    const [id, setId] = useState<string>("")
    const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>("")
    const [content, setContent] = useState<string>("")

    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(id, title, content)
        await createArticle(id, title, content)
    }

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen py-8 px-4 md:px-12">
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">ブログ新規作成</h2>
        <form
            className="bg-slate-200 p-6 rounded shadow-lg"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
            <div className="mb-4">
                <label className="text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">URL</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="shadow border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none"
                    onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-4">
                <label className="text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">タイトル</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="shadow border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none"
                    onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-4">
                <label className="text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">本文</label>
                <textarea
                    className="shadow border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none"
                    onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <button
                type="submit"
                className="py-2 px-4 roudned-md bg-orange-300"
            >
                投稿
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CreateBlogPage
```

- app/src/app/check/page.tsx

```
"use client"

import React from 'react'
import { createArticle  } from '@/blogAPI'

async function Check() {
  const id = "check"
  const title = "check-check"
  const content = "check-checedk-ffcheck"
  let is_res = false

  if (!is_res){
    const res = await createArticle(id, title, content)
    console.log(res)
    is_res = true
  }

  return (
    <div>Check</div>
  )
}

export default Check
```